# Copy warning when filtering dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, copy

I have a list of cars and their prices. I need to apply log transformation on the prices, but some prices are set to 0, so I first need to create a copy of my original df with the prices filtered out:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4'],
        'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand', 'Price'])

print (df)

df2 = df.loc[(df.Price>=22000) & (df.Brand=='Honda Civic')]

print(df2)

df2['logprice']=np.log(df2['Price'])
```

I get the warning

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

But I'm already using `.loc` !

I've read everything about this warning but I still don't understand what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make sure no warning add `copy`

```
df2 = df.loc[(df.Price>=22000) & (df.Brand=='Honda Civic')].copy()
df2['logprice']=np.log(df2['Price'])
```

Answer (score 1):

> But I'm already using .loc !

And it's your problem. Don't use it for assigning  a *copy* of your filtering rows. Use

```
df2 = df[(df.Price>=22000) & (df.Brand=='Honda Civic')]
```

instead.

---

*The explanation:*

The problem arises not in the mentioned command, but in the subsequent one:

```
df2['logprice']=np.log(df2['Price'])
```

which is in its left side interpreted as

```
df.loc[(df.Price>=22000) & (df.Brand=='Honda Civic')]['logprice']
```

Note the dangerous `][` — it's something that should be avoided on the left side of the assignment operator, because it may do change (adding a column in your case) not into *your* dataframe, but only into *some temporary object* (which will be destroyed by garbage collector).

Using

- `.loc[]` may provide a view or a copy (by context), while
- `[]` (which calls `.__getitem__()`  under the hood) **always returns a *copy***, so the left side  of the assignment

  ```
  df2['logprice']=np.log(df2['Price'])
  ```

will be not interpreted as I stated, but unambiguously as adding a new column to your *real* dataframe.

Comment: That's what I did initially. I added .loc to see if it removed the warning message but it didn't. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Negarev, I added a detailed explanation into my answer.